# how to run a python file in a package from Idle?

Tags: python, python-module, python-idle, python-packaging

I have a folder (python package):

```
app/
   __init__.py
   bases.py
   store.py
```

in `store.py` I have a the the code

```
from .bases import BaseStore

class Store(BaseStore):
    # .. class
```

Everything works when I run the full project.
How can I run the `store.py` file itself? 
Running the file with Idle gives an import error.
How can I run a script in idle which will be aware to its package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/10749432

Comment: BTW, try to remove dot from `.bases`. Simply try `from bases import BaseStore`. I think you don't need it.

Comment: I do need the dot as it is a relative import in the package. @TarasSavchyn This doesnt answer my question, I'm talking about running from idle

Comment: Are you running `store.py` from `app` folder? or outside of it?

Comment: from the app folder. I just right click store.py -> `Edit with IDLE` and then F5 to run

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is not an IDLE issue but one of the interaction between relative imports, sys.path, the current working directory, and how you start python.  To find out for sure, add the following at the top of `store.py`.

```
import os, sys
print(os.getcwd())
print(sys.path)
```

Then run your code the two different ways.  Also add, at a command line

```
python /path/to/app/store.py
```

This list is the equivalent of how IDLE runs your code.